# Getting error "Could not create task of type 'FlywayCleanTask'" when running build in Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, flyway

I've deployed successfully Flyway plugin for command-line where i run multiple oracle db scripts using parameters in flyway.sonfig file.

Now I'm trying to implement Flyway plugin for Gradel using the IntelliJ application.

I've created a dependency for the plugin:

```
dependencies {
   classpath "org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:4.0.2"
}
```

Run the build, and it looks like it downloaded the plugin successfully, I can see the Flyway tasks.

I've added new gradle.properties file with flyway parameters and when running the build now it gives an error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
>
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.flywaydb.flyway']
>
> Could not create task of type 'FlywayCleanTask'.

I don't understand what it means and why it fails.

Hope you can assist.

Comment: You have to provide whole exception stacktrace, because it contains the root cause of the problem

Comment: I understand.. thestacktrace is realy long but i found this row: Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.flywaydb.gradle.FlywayExtensio
n'

Comment: Seems you have something wrong within build script configuration. Could you share whole `build.gradle` content in question body?

Comment: ok it seems that i've included the flyway parameters in gradel.properties file not in the right way, i've correct it and it's fine now. thanks!